# Как распарсить такой формат времени 13.05.15.25? [JAVA]

Tags: java, время, формат

Как распарсить такой формат времени ? И создать дату

13 - день месяца,
5 - месяц,
15.00 - время = 15:00

Comment: А 25 это минуты? Секунды? Миллисекунды? Год?

Comment: `Date date = (new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.HH.mm")).parse("13.05.15.25");` или
`LocalDateTime dateTime = LocalDateTime.parse("13.05.15.25", DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd.MM.HH.mm"));`

Comment: Какой год Вы собираетесь использовать? Текущий?

Comment: @XelaNimed, да, текущий.

Насчет миллисекунд, мне нужно получать сколько осталось времени до указанной даты в миллисекундах, от сейчашнего времени, чтобы через это время отправлять уведомление

Comment: @Sergey у Вас ошибка формата не возникает при парсинге даты без года?

Comment: @XelaNimed идея Сергия выводит это: Wed May 13 15:25:00 IST 1970

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вместе с предложением Сергея получается такое решение:

```java
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.Year;
import java.time.temporal.ChronoField;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatterBuilder;

public class MyClass
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        String strDate = "13.05.15.25";
        String srcFormat = "dd.MM.HH.mm";
        String trgFormat = "yyyy.MM.dd HH:mm:ss";
        
        DateTimeFormatter srcFormatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
            .parseDefaulting(ChronoField.YEAR, Year.now().getValue())
            .appendPattern(srcFormat)
            .toFormatter();
        DateTimeFormatter trgFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( trgFormat );
        LocalDateTime localDateTime = LocalDateTime.parse( strDate , srcFormatter );
        
        System.out.println("strDate = " + strDate);
        System.out.println("localDateTime = " + localDateTime);
        System.out.println("localDateTime.format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE_TIME) = " + localDateTime.format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE_TIME));
        System.out.println("localDateTime.format(trgFormatter) = " + localDateTime.format(trgFormatter));
    }
}
```

---

#### Ссылки по теме:

[Онлайн/интерактивная версия кода](https://jdoodle.com/ia/qUn)
[DateTimeFormatter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html)
[LocalDateTime](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html)

Comment: Т.е. `LocalDateTime.parse("13.05.15.25", new DateTimeFormatterBuilder().parseDefaulting(ChronoField.YEAR , 2022).appendPattern( "dd.MM.HH.mm").toFormatter());`

Comment: @Sergey спасибо, сейчас поправлю...

Comment: Спасибо, это рабочий способ! Хотел бы узнать, правильно ли делать следующим образом: К примеру пользователь указывает какую-то дату, я получаю сколько осталось времени в миллисекундах до этой даты и делают таймер, чтобы через это время отправить сообщение пользователю

Comment: @vsvid я не знаю Вашу задачу и исходя из этого не могу сказать правильно-неправильно. Создайте новый вопрос, где полностью опишите Вашу задачу, то что Вы делаете и какой код используете.